# Profile is not searchable if targeted country is set

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I'm currently living in Argentina, and next week I'll be moving to New Zealand.
While updating my careers profile I decided to try the candidate search feature, and I realized that my profile is only discoverable if the 'Targeted countries' search field is not set, **or** it's set to Argentina (AR), even though I've changed my location to New Zealand site wide and in my careers profile, it even shows my location as 'Wellington, New Zealand' when my profile is returned.

Is there anything I can do about this behavior?, I'm somewhat worried my profile is not discoverable to potential employers who might make use of the 'Targeted countries' feature.

Comment: When did you change that?

Comment: It's probably a case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @rene, yesterday. I think around 16 hours ago, I thought it could be a replication issue between sites and stuff, but I thought more than 12hours should have been enough. I'll update if I notice any changes in the next few hours

Comment: This is a bug, looking into it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug had slipped through which inadvertently disabled our new Google geo-coding on the profile page. This then caused an older code path to execute which incorrectly updated your 'home' location to be Argentina. Doh!

It can take up to 24 hours for the candidate index to be updated but I've re-updated your profile and forced the index to refresh so you now appear in the relevant search results.

Comment: Excellent! It's working as expected now, thank you!